# JSON API user plugin is not working in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

after activating json api user plugin ,doesn't get user creation option in setting.API base is removed automatically.How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate all plugins except json api user plugin and then try, if still its not working then click inspect element and click on console and send me snap of it so i can look into it

Kind Regards
Tayyab